# SQL Time Difference Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| FileID  | EventDate | UserName | EventID |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       1 |
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       3 |
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       3 |
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       1 |
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       3 |
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       3 |
| 1000001 | DateTime  | User1    |       3 |
| 1000002 | DateTime  | User1    |       1 |
| 1000002 | DateTime  | User1    |       3 |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

I have a table with event data organized similar to the above example.  Each event has a FileID, EventID, UserName and a Datetime.  Event ID 1 is the user opening the file and Event ID 3 is a save event.   The final row with Event ID 3 indicates the file closing as each file is saved on closing.  I need to be able to sum the total time a user was in a file (time at final event 3 - time at event 1) but am having trouble figuring out how to do this if a user has entered a file multiple times.  Any ideas?

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: To be clear... you want the total time the user was 'in' the file... do you wish to include all the time (as you said, time between first open of file and last close of file), or do you want just the time in the file (in other words (first close - first open) + (second close - second open), etc)?  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @pmbAustin Thank you for the response.  I've tried grouping by FIleID and subtracting the min(EventDate) from the max(EventDate), Which gives me the time from the first open to the final close. What I want is your second example (first close - first open) + (second close - second open) etc...

Comment: What unit of measure do you want to use? Seconds, milliseconds, minutes,.....?

Comment: And what version of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for the replies. I'm working with SQL Server 2016.  Final unit of measurement I want is hour but it doesn't really matter, I'm not looking for specific code, just an idea of how I would do this.

Comment: This sounds like a "gaps and islands" problem. It has been asked and answered countless times.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table events (FileID int, EventDate datetime, UserName varchar(10), EventID int);
> insert into events values
> (1000001, '20180101 10:00:00', 'User1', 1 ),
> (1000001, '20180101 10:30:00', 'User1', 3 ),
> (1000001, '20180101 10:45:00', 'User1', 3 ),
> (1000001, '20180102 11:00:00', 'User1', 1 ),
> (1000001, '20180102 11:30:00', 'User1', 3 ),
> (1000001, '20180102 11:45:00', 'User1', 3 ),
> (1000001, '20180102 12:00:00', 'User1', 3 ),
> (1000002, '20180101 05:00:00', 'User1', 1 ),
> (1000002, '20180101 05:45:00', 'User1', 3 );
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select FileID, sum(minutes) totalTime
> from (
>       select FileID, grp, datediff(minute, min(EventDate), max(EventDate)) minutes
>       from (
>             select FileID, EventDate, UserName, EventID,
>                    sum(iif(EventID = 1,1,0)) over (order by FileID, EventDate) grp
>             from   events
>            ) t
>       group by FileId, grp
>      ) t2
> group by FileID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  FileID | totalTime
> ------: | --------:
> 1000001 |       105
> 1000002 |        45
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b81a675de65c35d4dbf212a51172d379)*

Comment: I like this answer much better than mine. One thing though, it won't take into account if there are other `EventIDs` than 1 and 3, and this could change the results if the last event is not a 3. If that isn't a concern, I'd go with this one. It's much more terse, and other than `iif()` (which can be worked around) doesn't use any features that are SQL2012+.

Answer (score 0):

Just make some fancy joins:

```
select fileID,userName,eventDate 'startDate',min(t2.eventDate) 'nextStart'
into #temp1
from logTable t1
left join logTable t2 on t1.fileID=t2.fileID and t1.userName=t2.userName and t2.eventID=1 and t1.eventDate<t2.eventDate
where t1.eventID=1
group by fileID,eventDate,userName

select fileID,userName,startDate,max(t2.eventDate) 'endDate'
from #temp1 t1
left join logTable t2 on t1.fileID=t2.fileID and t1.userName=t2.userName and t2.eventID=3 and t2.eventDate>t1.startDate and t2.eventDate<t1.nextStart
```

You wan't be able to get the the time spent though until the user opens the same file another time since you don't have a closestatus. But you could modify the second join to `...(t2.eventDate<t1.nextStart or t1.nextStart is null)` This will get the start time to the last savepoint

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEAD()` and `LAG()` again, so this is SQL2012+.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7a7c/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( FileID int, EventDate datetime, UserName varchar(20), EventID int ) ;
INSERT INTO t (FileID, EventDate, UserName, EventID)
VALUES 
    (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000','User1',1) /* OPEN 1 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:01:15.000','User1',3) /* SAVE 1 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:01:30.000','User1',3) /* CLOSE 1 */ /* 1 = 0:01:30 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:02:00.000','User1',1) /* OPEN 2 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:02:15.000','User1',3) /* SAVE 2 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:02:30.000','User1',3) /* SAVE 2 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:03:00.000','User1',3) /* SAVE 2 */
  , (1000002,'2018-02-01T00:00:00.500','User1',1) /* OPEN 1 */
  , (1000001,'2018-01-01T00:10:00.000','User1',3) /* CLOSE 2 */ /* 2 = 0:08:00 */
  , (1000002,'2018-02-01T00:01:00.000','User1',3) /* SAVE 1 */
  , (1000002,'2018-02-01T00:02:00.000','User1',3) /* CLOSE 1 */ /* 1 = 0:01:59.500 */
  , (1000088,'2018-02-10T00:00:00.000','NoCloseUser',1) /* OPEN - NOT CLOSED */
  , (1000099,'2018-02-10T00:00:00.000','NoOpenUser',3) /* CLOSED - NOT OPENED */
;
```

I added in a couple of bad records. One doesn't have a close date, but will still show up in the results. The is purely bad and didn't record an open date, but won't mess up the data. The Opened-But-Not-Closed record can be filtered in the query.

**Query**:

```
; WITH closes AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT t.FileID, t.UserName, t.EventDate, t.EventID
      , LEAD(t.EventID) OVER (PARTITION BY t.FileID, t.UserName ORDER BY t.EventDate) AS leadEvent 
    FROM t
  ) s1
  WHERE s1.EventID = 3 AND COALESCE(s1.leadEvent,1) = 1
)
, opens AS (
  SELECT t.FileID, t.UserName, t.EventDate
    , LEAD(t.EventDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY t.FileID, t.UserName ORDER BY t.EventDate ) AS nextOpen  
  FROM t 
  WHERE t.EventID = 1
)
SELECT s2.FileID, s2.UserName, SUM(minOpen) AS totalMinOpen 
FROM (
  SELECT o.FileID, o.UserName
    , o.EventDate as openDate
    , o.nextOpen
    , c.EventDate closeDate
    , c.leadEvent
    , DATEDIFF(second, o.EventDate,COALESCE(c.EventDate,getDATE()))/60.0 AS minOpen
  FROM opens o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN closes c ON o.FileID = c.FileID
    AND o.UserName = c.UserName
    AND o.EventDate <= COALESCE(c.EventDate,getDATE()) 
    AND ( c.leadEvent IS NOT NULL OR o.nextOpen IS NULL )
) s2
GROUP BY s2.FileID, s2.UserName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7a7c/2/0)**:

```
|  FileID |    UserName | totalMinOpen |
|---------|-------------|--------------|
| 1000001 |       User1 |          9.5 |
| 1000002 |       User1 |            2 |
| 1000088 | NoCloseUser |        28694 |
```

I use `LEAD()` and `LAG()` to determine the areas between where a file was closed and then opened again. I used CTEs to store the individual queries I used to determine the opens and closes. I diff'ed it out to seconds and then divided by 60.0 to get a decimal representation of the minutes. I'm sure this query can be optimized a bit.